# XCODE error: new file not built

Tags: c, xcode

So first I made a new project by going to File> OS X > Command Line Tool and chose C as the language. This is what I got:

[image]

Then I made a new C file called program.c:
[image]

Then I pressed run. It didn't build successfully:

[image]

However, when I deleted the first default file (main.c) and then pressed run program1.c....it built successfully.

My problem: Why can't I have several files under the same project and run them successfully?

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 main functions

Edit: each c program has to contain only one main function.
Other files of that program can not implement another main function.

Comment: Does that mean I can only have one C file under each project? I mean....to write the basic C programs I have learned, I need to use the main functions in all the files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11859631)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin, why do you think it's not an answer? the "2 main functions" is what causing his error

Answer (score 0):

Because you will have the main function declared in both files. I do not know how to tell XCode to build two separate applications..